# Windows 10/Apache/LAN how to access websites hosted on a different local computer?

Tags: windows-10, networking

I wish to access my local development websites hosted on a different local computer on my home network.

I have tried using http://192.168.1.nn and http://localhost in the browser and neither is found (my server computer has a static IP address of 192.168.1.nn).

When I run on computer nn, I have no trouble accessing localhost and its websites.

I have tried using Windows Settings to allow unauthenticated access to the nn computer (in the Defender Firewall, and also in Malwarebytes > Settings > Allow List > Add > 192.168.1.nn). I have tried using a port forwarding rule in the router to forward port mm to computer nn (and using address http://localhost:mm or http://192.168.1.nn:mm). I have tried adding this line to the Hosts file:

192.168.1.nn   localhost

I don't know very much about the internals of networking. I want to make a LAN-LAN Web connection on one of my computers to another, **without giving the outside world (WAN) access to anything** on my network. I am hoping to get help with answers that have been tested, so they work without too many questions and answers.

Comment: I cannot tell you what small integer nn is due to security concerns. I will never post my Apache configuration here for the same reason, and also because it is very long. What is it that you really are not understanding about my question?

Comment: Apologies. I think I misunderstood what you were looking for. I have added a list of general things for you to look into on your own.

Comment: The problem is most probably caused by a wrong configured webserver. Some things you did, like modifying the ```etc/hosts``` file are counterproductive and may introduces even more network issues. Your approach to not share your Apache config for security reasons is called "security by obscurity". This approach has turned out to be bad many times in the past: It is better to share your config with others, so they are able to point out security problems, than keeping it confidential and hope that nobody will find out about them.

Comment: I am not engaged in security in obscurity. I do not believe in it. I can't see how knowing the details of my home setup could help anyone break in. However, not all of security is the part dealing with encryption algorithms, which benefits from public testing. It is prudent to keep specific personal details private, to increase the difficulty of interference from malicious users.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem reluctant to provide additional information for security reasons, here are some general thoughts and comments on what you may wish to look at to help resolve this issue:

*Third-Party Applications*

- Disable any firewalls or virus-scanning during testing. Third-party applications or hardware may be affecting communications between the two computers, beyond whatever rules you have put in place.
- If you are using a virtual machine for your server, you may need to do additional configuration of the virtual machine itself (in addition to anything on the host) to allow access to it.
- Virtual machine software may have the option for "host-only" virtual network adapters that are never considered part of the local network. Make certain that you aren't attempting remote access via an IP assigned to any "host-only" network adapter (if present).
- Virtual machines may require port fowarding (via the virtual machine's software) to allow access to them, assuming they aren't running a bridged adapter.
- If you are using WSL, you may need to update it specifically or Windows generally.

*Local Networking*

- Ensure that the computers are on the same local network. Check the network mask on any routers. They should typically be the same. Also verify that any network DHCP servers (again, most likely on your router, etc.) are handing out the same ranges of local addresses to any devices you wish to be connected.
- Assuming a network mask of e.g. `255.255.255.0`, if your server has an address of  ex. `http://192.168.1.nn` and the computer you are using to access the server has an address of ex. `http://192.168.2.nn`, they are not on the same local network.
- Unless you have a special network setup which you haven't specified, port-forwarding in your router should be unnecessary for basic communication between devices on the same network.
- If you are attempting to use a mobile device to access your server from the local network, make certain you are using Wifi and not your carrier's data plan (since this would only be useful for testing WAN access).
- In general, you should only be using local addresses assigned by your router (i.e. not any IP assigned by your ISP).
- Broadly, using more than one router, using Wifi access points or using "advanced" networking equipment (e.g. mesh network hardware) could (theoretically) cause problems.

*Hostnames*

- The `hosts` file only applies to the computer it is present on. So a `hosts` file on the server will not allow other computers on the local network to resolve any hostnames it specifies. The `hosts` file on the computer attempting access would be the one that would need modification.
- `localhost` is not an arbitrary name. It almost always referrers *only* to the local computer. This means it typically cannot be used to refer to a remote server (i.e. one that isn't located on the same computer). Note that this can apply to virtual machines as well.
- Modifying `localhost` in `hosts` is possible, but may be ignored by browsers, with the browser instead simply returning a local loopback address (`ex. 127.0.0.1`) which is inaccessible remotely.
- If using Linux (say a Raspberry Pi or WSL), there may be some additional steps regarding resolver configuration that you may need to take in addition to editing your `hosts` file.
- For basic testing, you'll likely want to keep using IP addresses and avoid hostnames of any kind in order to limit connection issues to contacting the server itself, not the specific hostname.
- If you want to use hostnames without modifying `hosts` for each device, you will need to set up a local DNS server (and configure your router accordingly).
- You should have `hosts` entries or DNS entries which point to your server for any hostnames you wish access that server with.

*Apache*

- Ensure that Apache is running on the remote server.
- Though it won't prevent Apache from responding, if Apache doesn't have a virtual host for a given hostname, it may return either the default web page or possibly an error page.
- The configuration of your Apache server or its virtual hosts may deny you access from another computer, so double-check that there are no directives limiting access to your server. The settings for any `Require` directives are a good place to start (the value for these directives should typically be `all granted`).
- Inconsistencies or errors in your `ServerRoot` and `DocumentRoot` settings (as well as any `DocumentRoot` directory settings) in `httpd.conf` and/or any `DocumentRoot`/directory settings in a given virtual host may cause `403 Forbidden` responses.
- Using `.htaccess` files can limit access to the server depending on the settings in the files.
- Ensure that any `listen` directives (ex. in `httpd.conf`) are set to something like `listen 80` and/or `listen 443` rather than ex. `listen 127.0.0.1:80` or `listen 127.0.0.1:443`. The second type of directive chains Apache to listening only on `127.0.0.1`/`localhost` and it will discard requests from any computer that isn't the server itself.
- If you have set up Apache to `listen` on ports other than 80 or port 443 (the HTTP/HTTPS default ports), you need to include that port with the IP or hostname (e.g. `192.168.1.nn:8080` or `local-example:80`).
- Making any changes to an Apache requires restarting Apache for those changes to take effect.
- On Linux, with Debian/Ubuntu based systems, you may need to make symlinks from any files in your `sites-available` folder to your `sites-enabled` folder before restarting to have them available.

Comment: Thank you so much for this useful answer! While some issues you list are obviously not a problem for me, others bear examination. I will reply when I've had a chance to do more experimenting.

Comment: Your welcome. I hope you fix your issue. Looking forward to hearing how it goes. =)